How to set invoice line item data from array of object?
I am processing multiple invoices and it's line level data using scheduled script.
Below is array of objects.
Var JEIDArray = [ { item: "663", amount: "3000.00", JE: 13026407, invId: "13020561" }, { item: "663", amount: "100.00", JE: 13026408, invId: "13020561" }, { item: "663", amount: "111.00", JE: 13026409, invId: "13026406" }, { item: "663", amount: "222.00", JE: 13026410, invId: "13026406" }, { item: "373", amount: "444.00", JE: 13026411, invId: "13026406" } ];
Here I am getting invoice ids redundant. So I have to load every invoice every time and then set line level values. How I can avoid loading same invoice multiple times, but set line level data on correct invoices?
Please help!
Below is function to update invoice lines:
function updateInvoice(JEIDArray) {
try {
        //var currentInvoiceId = null;
        for (var r=0;r<JEIDArray.length;r++)
        {
        var getRecId=JEIDArray[r].invId;
        log.debug("getRecId",getRecId);
        
        //currentInvoiceId=getRecId;
        
        var invoice = record.load({
            type: record.Type.INVOICE,
            id: getRecId,
            isDynamic: false
        })
    
        // Get the number of invoice lines
        var lineCount = invoice.getLineCount({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });
        log.debug("lineCount", lineCount);

        // Loop through each invoice line
        for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
            var currentItemId = invoice.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'item',
                line: i
            });
            var currentItemAmount = invoice.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol_ay_cts_allocation_amount',
                line: i
            });

            // Loop through each item in JEIDArray
            var flag = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < JEIDArray.length; j++) {
                var jeItem = JEIDArray[j];
                if (currentItemId == jeItem.item && currentItemAmount == jeItem.amount) {
                    //log.debug("Item and amount flag in JEIDArray: ", currentItemId, currentItemAmount);
                    flag = true;
                    invoice.setSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'custcol_ay_cts_assoc_ic', // Replace with your desired custom field
                        line: i,
                        value: jeItem.JE
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                //log.debug("Item or amount not flag in JEIDArray: ", currentItemId, currentItemAmount);
            }
        }
        // Update the invoice if necessary
        var invoiceId=invoice.save();
        log.debug('Invoice Updated', `Invoice ID: ${invoiceId}`);
    }


Group the data by invId before iterating. There are a lot of ways to do this; personally I'd use reduce() on the Array, like so:
JEIDArray.reduce((data, line) => {
  data[line.invId] ??= []
  data[line.invId].push(line)
  return data
}, {})

This will result in an Object like
{
  "13020561": [
    {
      "item": "663",
      "amount": "3000.00",
      "JE": 13026407,
      "invId": "13020561"
    },
    {
      "item": "663",
      "amount": "100.00",
      "JE": 13026408,
      "invId": "13020561"
    }
  ],
  "13026406": [
    {
      "item": "663",
      "amount": "111.00",
      "JE": 13026409,
      "invId": "13026406"
    },
    {
      "item": "663",
      "amount": "222.00",
      "JE": 13026410,
      "invId": "13026406"
    },
    {
      "item": "373",
      "amount": "444.00",
      "JE": 13026411,
      "invId": "13026406"
    }
  ]
}

Once you have this Object, you can iterate through each Invoice via Object.keys(). All of this assumes you are using SuiteScript 2.1.
